# How to change the space between '<' and 'back' of the BackBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios

Is there any way to change the space between '<' and 'back' of the BackBarButtonItem instead of using a custom back button? I just want to adjust the space of the system back button and it is enough. So I think custom a button is unnecessary. Any idea?
[image]

Comment: you can't play with the system back button,But yes u can create custom one and get ur objective done.

Comment: if i want to play with the system one, how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to customize all back buttons. Just put your code of creating button in NavigationContrller Class, and hide it in rootViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer to my question just now.Actually, apple api provide us such a way to do the trick `setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment`
reference from 'apple develop class reference'[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:]

Also,I read a demo from a Chinese blog.[http://phaibin.tk/2013/08/05/ioszhong-zi-ding-yi-dao-lan-de-hou-tui-an-niu]

My way to do this is :

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
[newBackButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16],NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[newBackButton setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-8, 0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:newBackButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write empty title to previous navigation controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"";
 }
```